# Error: 'Missing return in a function expected to return Int'

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, return

The first function below works fine to check for FM values, but when I added some validation in an else if statement for the AM values, I am getting error message saying:  `Missing return in a function expected to return Int`. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the placement of the curly braces.

```
        static var minAMFFrequency: Double = 520.0
        static var maxAMFFrequency: Double = 1610.0
        static var minFMFFrequency: Double = 88.3
        static var maxFMFFrequency: Double = 107.9

    func isBandFM() -> Int {
        if frequency >= RadioStation.minFMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxFMFFrequency {
            return 1 //FM
        } else {
            return 0 //AM
        }
    }
```

Modified function with error:

```
func isBandFM() -> Int {
        if frequency >= RadioStation.minFMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxFMFFrequency {
            return 1 //FM
        } else if frequency >= RadioStation.minAMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxAMFFrequency{
            return 0 //AM
        }
    }
```

Comment: What should `isBandFM()` return if `frequency` is neither in the AM or FM band? The compiler can't guess for you.

Comment: If you end up writing something like `return 1 //FM`, that's a code smell. You knew the `1` is unclear, so you felt the need to explain it with a comment. Instead, you should consider replacing `Int` (which is a very "weak" type in this context), with something "stronger" and more self-descriptive, like `enum`. I suggest you check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to consider cases that do not fall in the 2 conditions. It expects you to provide a default return value.

In the first case, you had a default value of 0 being returned.

In the second case, if your `frequency` is neither in the first range (specified by the first `if` condition) nor in the second range (specified by the second `if` condition), you need to specify a default return value.

```
func isBandFM() -> Int {
        if frequency >= RadioStation.minFMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxFMFFrequency {
            return 1 //FM
        } else if frequency >= RadioStation.minAMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxAMFFrequency{
            return 0 //AM
        }

        return 0   // or whatever value you want to return if frequency is not within FM range or AM range
}
```

Comment: thanks Sanil - this fixed the error and I'll include code here to cover any out of bounds values.

Answer (score 1):

Sanil already explained the issue here, but I'll suggest some other improvements

This is better expressed using the appropriate types:

1. A `Range<Double>` instead of two seperate `Double`s
2. A `Boolean` instead of a `0`/`1` `Int`.
3. An `enum` to represent named frequency bands, like "AM", "FM", or "other"

```
struct RadioStation {
    enum Band {
        case am, fm, other
    }
    static let amFrequencyRange = 520.0...610.0
    static let fmFrequencyRange = 88.3...107.9

    let frequency: Double

    var isFM: Bool { RadioStation.fmFrequencyRange.contains(frequency) }
    var isAM: Bool { RadioStation.amFrequencyRange.contains(frequency) }

    var band: Band {
        if self.isFM { return .fm }
        else if self.isAM { return .am }
        else { return .other }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble. Really appreciate your help and this amazing refactoring. It's beyond helpful!

Comment: Can I change the struct to be a class? The idea is that RadioStation is the class definition, from which I create an FM and an AM station also. Can I do this with a struct as opposed to a class?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a class? "The idea is that RadioStation is the class definition, from which I create an FM and an AM station also" yep. You should read about structs, and the Swift langauge guide more generally: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: I thought classes were for subclassing when you want to create separate instances based on the class definition? I need to learn about passing by value vs by reference.

Comment: I'm creating separate RadioStation objects which will use this class's methods and properties. Is that not cause enough, no?

Comment: None of that is specific to classes. Please read the Swift language guide.